# Doing image processing in the browser using GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, image-processing

I want to write a simple web application in which image synthesis is done in the browser. I will have a server that serves procedural image information (expressions), and the clients should be able to use these messages to generate and display images. Can this sort of task be done entirely in the web browser (using GWT, preferably)?

Answer (score 2):

You will have some major browser restrictions, but you can try using either HTML5 canvas or I have also noticed that the Firefox implementation of ImageResource compiles to a url containing data: followed by some sort of bitmap, so you could support non-html5 versions of FF.  However I believe IE will be out of the question until IE9.  I believe the thin image editing client used in Picassa web albums uses server-side rendering.  Also, eventually you might want to look into the Chrome native API if you are doing any heavy image processing.